# change the date format excel into US format

Tags: excel, date-formatting

I have a date format in Excel as `10-04-2017` (10th of April) but I want it as `10/04/2017` (04th of October US format) how to do so?

I have already tried changing the short date format in control panel and it didn't help

Comment: Did you mean 04/10/2017?

Comment: Are you opening a text file which has all dates in dd-mm-yyyy format? Or are you opening an Excel file that already has dates as dd-mm-yyyy, with  some stored as dates and some stored as text? Or is it an Excel file with all dates with dd-mm-yyyy formatting and you just need to change the formatting? A screenshot might help.

Answer (score 2):

Highlight the range of cells you wish to format then go to Number tab on ribbon, click the bottom right hand expand arrow

[image: Change date]

Go to Date then change the locale to US and select how you want the date to be presented.